# Get Table conditions SQL

Tags: sql

I have this table in SQL:

| Date | Price | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16/11/2020 | 45.2 | -1000 |
| 16/11/2020 | 45.2 | -500 |
| 17/11/2020 | 48 | 800 |
| 16/11/2020 | 46 | 200 |
| 16/11/2020 | 46 | 200 |

and I need a query that return the sum of lines with quantity less than zero and more than zero separated and grouped by date. The query should return a table like this:

| Date | Price | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16/11/2020 | 45.2 | -1500 |
| 16/11/2020 | 46 | 400 |
| 17/11/2020 | 48 | 800 |

I was trying to use Group by but I had difficulties to use that.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  You should also show your atempt.

Comment: Do you actually need to separate negatives and positives here, or can we group just across the date and price?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the description, it seems like you want a group based on negative and positive `quantity` along with `date`.

You have not tagged your question with any database but you can use the standard sql `case .. when` as follows:

```
Select date, price, sum(quantity) as quantity
  From your_table t
Group by date, price, case when quantity < 0 the 1 else 2 end;
```

If you dont want the result to be groupped by `price` then you can remove the `price` from the `group by` clause and use `max(price)` or any aggregate function as per your requirement in the `select` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Group and count positive and negative numbers separately. Then merge the results together using UNION or UNION ALL.

You can also sort result as you want by enclosing the query into brackets to nested query - inner query for getting data, outer qyuery for filtering and sorting.

```
select Date,Price, sum(Quantity)
from yourtable
where Quantity>0
group by Date,Price

union

select Date,Price, sum(Quantity)
from yourtable
where Quantity<0
group by Date,Price
```

or with sorting result

```
select Date,Price, Quantity
    from (
        select Date,Price, sum(Quantity) as Quantity
            from yourtable
            where Quantity>0
            group by Date,Price
        union
        select Date,Price, sum(Quantity)
            from yourtable
            where Quantity<0
             group by Date,Price
    ) detail
    order by Date, Quantity
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -3):

I think this is just `group by`.  The price distinction seems sufficient.  There is no need to separate the quantities.

```
select date, price, sum(quantity)
from t
group by date, price;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d99eba5cb6eb3d58f7fb08c2e0b20e2d) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I believe this is missing the "quantity less than zero and more than zero separated" requirement of the original question.  To me that would mean separate results for positive and negative quantities.

Comment: I don't actually think that is necessary given the data that the OP provided.